# random shape instead of circle in pack layout in d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, shapes, circle-pack

Is it possible to change the shape of the circle to some random shape in d3 pack layout

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530

I need to change the shape of circles to polygon.

Comment: You can use any shape you want, but they won't be "packed", meaning that there may be overlap or gaps.

Comment: Has anyone seen examples of this implemented?